# Python About using regular expression in pandas for integer search

Tags: python, django, pandas

I used django for a search feature improvement，Enter the character you want to search, convert it to an integer to match the specified field, The search results will output the rows that match the search results，so it has been done so far

```
new_fmr = '26660000'
new_fmt = int(new_fmt)
some1 = df[(df[19].str[:8] == new_fmt )]
```

```
##Mre
data = {'index':['CNP','NON','NON'],
       'CNP':[26660000,26660002,26660003],
       'CNPN':[26663322,26663322,26663333]}
df = DataFrame(data)
new_fmr = '26660000'##user can only input str
new_fmr = int(new_fmr)
some1 =df[(df['CNP'] == new_fmr)]
print(some1)
```

user input is new_fmt,  but user need to input the exact corresponding input, so what I want to ask is like, when user input 26660000, The code separates The first four inputs and assigns The last four to [0-9] [0-9] [0-9] [0-9], after using regular expression input to four matches, **such as user input: 26660000, The matches of 26660000-26669999 are displayed in dataframe，Instead of just matching the output 26660000** .

When I looked up other materials, I learned that re can only be used for str, while the table I imported in pd is int, so this bothers me a lot. I hope to get a solution, thank you

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That means a code I can quickly copy and run on my system. Right now, I don't know what variables `df` and `some1` stand for. Also split your question into more paragraphs and don't mark so much text as bold. Thank you.

Comment: Made some improvements. Is there anything else I need to add